# Apply CSS to specific Span Style inside a DIV Class

Tags: css

Have a webpage where we can't alter the HTML but we can add custom CSS.
My issue is to set the `"text-align:right"` to the first SPAN STYLE only. How do I do this?

```html
<div class="pull-right" style="display: table; padding-bottom: 8px;">
 <span style="display: table-cell; padding-right: 1em; width: 90px; vertical-align: middle;">kr 115,00 x</span>
 <span style="display: table-cell; width: 75px; border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">1</span>
 <span style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 1em; width: 95px; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;">= kr 115,00</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CSS pseudo-class [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) to target the first element in a container.

```
.pull-right span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this CSS:

```
.pull-right span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```